# What is difference between socket.receive(buff,0,buff.length) and socket.receive(buff, buff.length,0)?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm new in socket so I don't know what it the difference between socket.receive(buff,0,buff.length) and socket.receive(buff, buff.length,0)? I used recieve method many times but don't know differences.

Comment: The latter asks to receive 0 bytes, so would never be useful as far as I'm aware. Did you read the documentation for `Socket.Receive` and for the parameters in particular?

Comment: can you explain me a bit.

Comment: Have a look on this link will answer your query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.8.  Receive(Byte[], Int32, SocketFlags) looks appropriate to your call for mentioned second call.

Comment: Your question's unclear. The answer to what you're literally asking is obvious. Too obvious to be the basis for a real answer. It seems you likely have a specific reason for asking this. What is the context here? You say you've used `Receive()` "many times", presumably never with the latter syntax. And presumably you've read the documentation, so you understand what each parameter means. So please explain why you don't already know the answer to the question. How did this come up? Why did that present this to you as a _practical_ programming problem? What does your question really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got some information from Microsoft website.**

**Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, SocketFlags)**

```
Receives the specified number of bytes from a bound Socket into the
specified offset position of the receive buffer, using the specified
SocketFlags.
```

**Receive(Byte[], Int32, SocketFlags)**

```
Receives the specified number of bytes of data from a bound Socket
into a receive buffer, using the specified SocketFlags.
```

for more information visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.8